# My Dell studio 14" doesn't load boot bios, OS and even firmware

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair, dell-studio

Dell studio 14" doesn't load boot bios, OS and even firmware it only displays gray light and after some time laptop shutdowns.
It doesn't even read any external drive.
Could any one help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your laptop is under warranty I would contact Dell.  Even if its not this sounds like a problem only the OEM is able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite enough information, but from what little you described, it sounds like you tagged it correctly. "hardware-failure" ... in need of "laptop-repair". It would be helpful if you described what may have led up to this behavior - e.g. did you drop it? Was it getting hot? Was the fan coming on a lot before? Did it get a virus?

Is it still under warranty?

Some things to try:

- Remove any drives you can and try to boot into BIOS
- Remove battery and try to boot into BIOS